# Is there a way to add custom (debug) keys in elasticSearch query syntax

Tags: elasticsearch

While debugging pretty complex queries, I wonder if there is a way to add some debug informations elastic engine will ignore while parsing queries.
Using the following results in http 400 answer with error `x_content_parse_exception` `[bool] unknown field [debug]`.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "debug": "base query",
            "must": [
                {
                    "debug": "date not in futur",
                    "range": {
                        "date_add": {
                            "lte": "2022-10-26 14:08:11"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "debug": "index X",
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "_index": "X"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [...],
            "should": [...]
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find anything regarding an authorised (ignored) custom key in elastic documentation.

I already figured out I can build my queries with that debug infos and just remove them before sending to elastic engine but if there is an easier way, I would love to know it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#named-queries) for this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "date_add": {
                            "lte": "2022-10-26 14:08:11"
                        },
                        "_name": "date not in futur",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "_index": "X",
                                    "_name": "index X"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [...],
            "should": [...]
        }
    }
}
```